# Categorical version of the Tietze Extension Theorem

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

In Donald Hartig's short paper [*An Important Functor in Analysis and Topology*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2978049?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Theorem 1 is preceded by the following statement:

> Since the spaces we are dealing with are compact, a one-to-one map will be a homeomorphic embedding and the following result could be called a categorical version of the Tietze Extension Theorem.

I don't understand the relationship between the two parts of the sentence: why does the fact injective maps on compact spaces are homeomorphic embeddings justify calling Theorem 1 a categorical version of the TET?

**Added (BMS):**

> **Theorem** $\mathbf{1}.$ Let $\alpha:X\to Y$ be a morphism in *Comp*; then $\alpha$ is one-to-one if and only if $\alpha^*$ is onto.

Here *Comp* is the family of continuous maps between compact Hausdorff spaces, and for $\alpha:X\to Y$ in *Comp* the map $\alpha^*:C(Y)\to C(X)$ is defined by $\alpha^*(f)=f\circ\alpha$ for each $f\in C(Y)$.

Comment: Please state theorem 1 (as the paper is behind a pay-wall).

Answer (score 2):

The connection is explained in the material that immediately precedes the sentence that you quoted. If $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and $X$ is a closed subset of $Y$, then $X$ is also a compact Hausdorff space, and the natural embedding $\iota:X\to Y:x\mapsto x$ is continuous and one-to-one. Theorem $1$ then says that $\iota^*$ maps $C(Y)$ onto $C(X)$. Let $f\in C(X)$ be arbitrary.

- The Tietze extension theorem says that there is a $g\in C(Y)$ such that $f=g\upharpoonright X$.
- Theorem $1$ says that $\iota^*$ maps $C(Y)$ onto $C(X)$. This means that there is a $g\in C(Y)$ such that $g\circ\iota=\iota^*(g)=f$, and since $\iota$ is the identity map on $X$, this in turn simply says that $f=g\upharpoonright X$.

In other words, in this (somewhat limited) context the Tietze extension theorem and the more interesting direction of Theorem $1$ say the same thing.

Comment: This is even clearer than the author's article. What I am missing is: what we gain from this categorical reformulation? And why shold the functor described in the article  be deemed important, as in the title. I mean: I discovered this article reading the same author's "The RIesz Representation Theorem Revised". There it is clear that the categorical reformulation is profound and moreover it provides an anlytical example of natural transformation, an elusive concept to a beginner. Here what is the gist of the article ?